# Job exporting tables to file every 15 minutes and calling PHP script once done

Tags: php, mysql, abap, jobs

I've been doing a lot of researching for a potential job where I will need to periodically (every 15 minutes) export some specific data from SAP and then import that data into a mySQL database on a separate server.

So far I have gathered that this could be the workflow:

1) Create ABAP program on SAP server that selects required data and outputs to file (sql, csv, tab delimited etc) on external server

2) Once step 1 is complete, call a php file on external server that imports data into mySQL database.

I have a few questions:

a) Can the ABAP program be scheduled to run every 15 minutes? From the screenshots I have seen of the scheduling tool, the increment seems to be in hours

b) Is there a notification/event dispatched once the data has been exported and uploaded to an external server? This way I will know when to call the import .php script.

c) I will only be wanting to import new data added to SAP since the last scheduled run of the ABAP program, will this be easy to implement?

Also, if anyone can suggest improvements on my workflow then I would love to hear them!

Thanks so much

Comment: Based on the responses I feel I should add some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ) sure, there are jobs with steps in them, which are supposed to run programs, which for themselves   can be parametrized with variants. The flexibility is very good. check SM36 and SM37 for that.

B ) Do not know. check C ).

You should change the approach. The SQL Server can offer a module, which is called from the SAP-System in an RFC Destination ( SM59, TCP/IP connection, Registered Serverprogramm ).
If set up via job, the SAP will make a call to the sql server, which could offer a php module to be accessed via rfc call ( tcp/ip ) . The data is transferred by sap with the help of calling a module inside the sql server. Data is translated as tables, if You like so.
You would not need to save a file in between the process. If Your sap calls the other module, and it returns with error, then and only then You could create a file ( or buffer in db table to transfer the data the next time).
C) If You directly pass the data to Your sql server, then there You can decide via php, if the data is to drop or to insert.

You should read here for further details:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/index?rid=/webcontent/uuid/5d9fb155-0b01-0010-8e8a-d8703df8bb9e

Comment: So to be clear, you are suggesting SAP directly passes data to a method in a php script, which will then populate the db?

Answer (score 1):

you should look at Winshuttle query, it doesn't require abap development and targets a variety of data formats , more importantly, you can schedule it and wrap a workflow.

Comment: This does seem useful, unfortunately it is not free which makes it unsuitable for me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - the entire "requirement" seems to be horribly wrong. Why would you want to off-load DBMS processing from the central high-end system to some satellite? You don't give any valid reasons, and I don't want to speculate. As for your questions.

a) No idea what screenshots you have seen so far, but the scheduling system is able to run jobs every minute, if you really want to bring the system down.

b) There is one of you implement it in your ABAP program.

c) This depends on the data. As I said, your approach sounds horribly wrong, but without further information, it's impossible to give concrete advice.

Comment: Currently data reports are already being output from the SAP system to a tab delimited file (this was all set up by someone else), this is why I suggested utilising these report files to populate the SQL db.  The reason I am intending to create a separate db is because I will be pulling and combining data from multiple SAP tables, think of it like a data warehouse. I also want clients to be able to poll the database without causing strain on the main SAP database.